# Identifying a television special about time travel and Martin Luther King, Jr

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

I remember that years and years ago I watched some television special in school about some kid traveling back in time to meet a young Martin Luther King, Jr. before he became a civil rights activist. The kid takes young King back to his time to find that he has messed with the timeline by doing so, with American schools not being racially equal. So, he takes him back to his original time. Some other things happen, I think. I don't know. Can someone help me identify this?

Comment: Schmoyoho? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GbmUXhZlYHc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ***[Our Friend, Martin](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Our_Friend,_Martin)*** is a 1999 direct-to-video animated children's educational film about Martin Luther King Jr. and the Civil Rights Movement. Two friends travel through time, meeting Dr. King at several points during his life. It featured an all-star voice cast and was nominated for an Emmy award in 1999 for Outstanding Animated Program (For Programming More Than One Hour). It was also the final release under the CBS/Fox Video name.

[image]